# What should the Help Center say about the questions we don't allow?

Tags: discussion, scope

The Help Center have a section titled [*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) It is still empty, but it should list which questions are allowed, and which not, in the same same it does the equivalent section of [this Stack Exchange site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

> [image: screenshot]

What questions should be listed as off-topic, for esperanto.stackeschange.com?

Comment: I think we shouldn't be that strict about what's on-topic and what's not during the private beta. It could be better to vote to close if one _thinks_ that some question is off-topic for now. Then, when the site is more established (perhaps, after a week of public beta), some rules may be added.

Comment: The question is not about the private beta phase. If you look at other meta sites, you will notice there are similar questions.

Comment: In fact, the Help Center section I am referring will be editable only from moderators. It will not br edited until the site doesn't reach the public beta phase, when the site will have pro-tempore moderators.

Comment: I'm going to close this as too broad (for now). See my extended discussion below: http://meta.esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/15/what-should-the-help-center-say-about-the-questions-we-dont-allow/19#19

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Over the years, we've found it generally more helpful to forgo these all-encompassing scope/rules discussions in favor of talking about very specific problems when they come up in actual practice.

**This site is about Esperanto.** I would begin your days embracing a broad range of interests so we don't start off by flogging newcomers with a patchwork of what on and off topic on this site.

In other words… let's not be too quick to jump on hypothetical problems until they become somewhat unworkable in actual practice. We have found that avoiding these forced rules discussions has worked *exceedingly* well for our newer sites; it makes for a much friendlier community overall. We may eventually need to enumerate some bullet points regarding what's on topic for the "help center", but it is way too early for that.

If you have a specific concern about something you're seeing on the site,  please feel free to post a separate discussion about it here (on meta); but for now, I am going to **close this thread as 'too broad'.**

Answer (score -1):

Off the top of my head:

- Translation requests
- Translation reviews ([source](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25212/permissability-of-translation-reviews))
- Questions in languages other than English/Esperanto ([source](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23239/would-topics-in-any-language-be-welcome))

Comment: Should word-requests be on topic, like in english.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I think questions about the translation of single words should certainly be considered on topic. What should be considered off topic are translation requests for extended texts.